# Why does my function work with `df` and `cat` but not `ps`?

Tags: bash

I often have a command where I get a table of information and I'd like to grep for something in the table *but* when I do that, I tend to lose the header information. The canonical information of this is `ps`, where I might do `ps -aux | grep firefox` to see the PID of my Firefox process, but then I don't know what the columns refer to. So I wrote this function that preserves the first `n` lines of the table and pipes the rest into `grep`:

```
# Keep the first n(default to 1) lines and pass the rest through grep
grepn () {
    num_lines=1

    # Parse flags to extract -n
    if [[ "$1" =~ -n(=.+)? ]]; then
        if [[ "$1" == *=* ]]; then
            num_lines="${1#*=}"
        else
            shift
            num_lines=$1
        fi
        if [[ ! $num_lines =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
            echo "Invalid number of lines: ${num_lines}";
            return -1
        fi
        shift
    fi

    tee >(head -n $num_lines) >(tail -n +$((1+$num_lines)) | grep "$@") >/dev/null
}
```

If I pipe `df -h` into this, it works perfectly, I get as many header lines as I want, plus only the table lines that contain the thing I'm grepping for (e.g. `df -h | grepn sda1`). However, when I pipe `ps -aux` into this, I only ever get the header line. The same behavior is exhibited by the minimal version of this:

```
ps -aux | tee >(head -1) >(tail -n +2 | grep firefox) >/dev/null
```

Which always gives:

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

If I redirect the output of `ps -aux` to a file, then `cat` the file into `grepn`, that works as expected.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** I don't have the answer to "why is this happening" yet, but in the comments [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) has suggested an alternative approach that I've adapted to fit my needs that seems to be working:

```
# Replaces the line starting with `tee`
for (( i=0; i < num_lines; i++ )); do
    IFS= read -r line
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
grep "$@"
```

Comment: Try adding a file to your tee outputs so you can replay the rest of the pipeline with canned output from `ps` _as that output exists while your function is running_.

Comment: (mind, in general, this is race-condition-laden code; remember that all parts of a pipeline run concurrently -- so both the `head -1` and the `tail -n +2 | grep firefox` are running at the same time, and there's no firm guarantee that `head` will flush its output before `grep` does)

Comment: that said, _on MacOS_, I don't get the result you say this "always" provides -- `ps` results are returned from the minimal/one-line variant.

Comment: Have you considered `ps aux | { IFS= read -r line; printf '%s\n' "$line"; grep firefox; }`? No `tee` needed, the content past the first line makes it to the `grep` because the `read` only consumes up to the first newline, and far fewer moving parts making things complicated or race-prone in general.

Comment: Side note: to parse the `-n` parameter, you could use [`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-getopts), which does all the work for you.

Comment: I knew it was a race condition, but so far the `grep` command basically always finishes second, and I didn't think it was worth my time trying to figure out how to make blocking calls (since if the header comes second it might even be better, TBH). A modified version of your `read`/`printf` one-liner seems to be working great. ☺

Comment: Because of how `head` and `tail` work, it's not safe to have them both read from the same input file. `head` may only *output* one line, but it's not guaranteed to *read* only one line in order to determine what to output. It's also guaranteed that `head` reads from the shared input descriptor before `tail` does.

Comment: @BenjaminW.I was originally using `getopts`, but `getopts` wants to parse *all* the arguments, and I want to pass everything except the `-n` parameter into `grep`, in case I want to do something like `my_command | grepn -n 5 -B 2 thing_to_find`.

Comment: I'd suggest `for ((i=0; i<num_lines; i++))` to avoid needing `seq` (which is neither built-in, nor standardized).

Comment: @chepner, ...right, but `tee` is splitting the stream before reaching either -- and it's documented to keep writing to other destinations even if one closes -- so if the OP's original code was combining `head` and `tail` in an unsafe way, I'm not spotting it on a read. (I'd still like to see an example of a file created via passing a filename as an extra argument to `tee` during a run in which the tool unexpectedly has no output).

Comment: @Paul regarding `grepn -n 5 -B 2 thing_to_find`, you can use `getopts` and do `grepn -n 5 -- -B 2 thing_to_find`.

Comment: why on earth do you use `ps` to get PID of a process? Just use `pidof firefox` or `pgrep -l firefox`. And in case `ps aux` is used then the common way to get rid of `grep` itself is to use a character class of a single character: `ps aux | grep [f]irefox`

Comment: **Use `sed` instead of `grep`!!!** You could simply: `ps aux | sed -ne '1p;/firefox/p'`

Comment: ... like`df -hl | sed -ne '1p;/ \/$/p'` of `df -hl | sed -ne '1p;\- /$-p'`

Comment: Or `awk`: `ps -ef | awk "(NR==1){print} /cups/{print}"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point. (And while rereading my comment, I noticed I left out a critical "not": the `head` subprocess is *not* guaranteed to run first, but again not an issue since they are reading from separate streams produced by `tee`.)

Comment: FWIW I voted to re-open because my question is "why doesn't this work with `ps`", not "how do I do this", which the linked questions do not answer. I suspect there's a difference with how `ps` terminates its output or something, or something about the interaction between `ps` and `tee`. I think it might be worth understanding in cases where the solution isn't to just not use `tee`.

Comment: @Paul, fair, but the details I asked for at least twice (content of `sample.txt` after running `ps -aux | tee sample.txt >(head -1) >(tail -n +2 | grep firefox) >/dev/null` and getting no output) are really essential to answering that (at least, for people who can't reproduce the stated behavior locally -- and, again, I can't); and to date you haven't yet provided them; so even if this weren't closed as a duplicate, it would arguably be eligible for close as lacking a [mre].

Comment: If the content of `sample.txt` _didn't_ allow reproducing the behavior, then we'd be looking at `strace -f -s 2048 -o pipe.strace bash -c 'ps -aux | tee sample.txt >(head -1) >(tail -n +2 | grep firefox) >/dev/null'` to get a log that can be followed to see what's going on -- but insofar as digging through a strace log with this many moving parts is quite a lot of work, I'm _really_ hoping it doesn't come to that.

Comment: @Charles Duffy when i start ```ps -aux | tee >(head -1 > file1) >(tail >file2)```, i see, that tail does not get the whole output of ps aux, so i thought tee is sending a stream end, but when i start ```ps aux | tee >(while IFS= read -r line; do output+=$line$'\n'; done; echo -n "$output" > file1) >(while IFS= read -r line; do output+=$line$'\n'; done; echo -n "$output" > file2)``` its all correct, so tee cant be the problem, i think

Comment: @Paul I'm on Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy and can confirm your problem, i also get no output with your one liner

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza, I'm not proposing that tee is the problem; I'm proposing that tee can be used to record what's happening when the problem takes place, to allow the OP to build a [mre] others can run even when their local systems don't exhibit the problem otherwise. (Mind, I'm also not saying `tee` _isn't_ the problem -- if it is, we'd want more copies to rule that out; `ps aux | tee stage1 >(tee stage2 | head -1 >file1) >(tee stage3 | tail -n +2 | grep firefox >file3)` f/e would allow analysis of what's going into each pipeline so they can be rerun individually).

Comment: @Charles Duffy i know, what is happening here after stracing ```strace -f -s 1024 -o trace bash -c 'ps -aux | tee >(head -1 >file1) >(tail >file2)' ```,  ps command sends the first 4096 bytes to tee, tee reads it, and send it to STDOUT, then tee send it to head, head reads it, tee writes to tail, tail reads it,  then head does a illegal seek ```lseek(0, -4021, SEEK_CUR)= -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)  and writes to STDOUT which goes to file 1 and exits,  ps is generating the next 4096 bytes, then writes it to tee, tee reads it, and send it on the same FD to head, but head has exited, tee got broken

Comment: @Charles Duffy broken pipe, and is killed by SIGPIPE, then tail finishes, after the first 4096 bytes, because tee got killed, and finally ps got killed because of broken pipe (tee is killed), if someone would open the thread i can post the complete trace.

Comment: The trace is probably too long to be allowed here; it would make more sense to link to a gist.

Comment: See the CONSEQUENCES OF ERRORS section in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html

Comment: @Charles Duffy I'm sorry, but i dont report a bug on a core utility, if no expert has a look before. Im just a newbie, who is learning from you. I didnt know strace command, before you post it here. I invested one hour in learning to understand straces output. I have an account on JSFiddle and put all the information in a HTML file. Its up to an expert, to have a look at it, at https://jsfiddle.net/Veryape/pguoyx93/81/ . I've learned in this thread two things, strace, and never use tee with head in a process substitution

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza, ...reopened, and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue does not occur on systems with BSD tee -- it's a GNUism.

If you want GNU tee to ignore pipe errors, you need to pass the `-p` argument.

That is:

```
ps -aux | tee -p >(head -1) >(tail -n +2 | grep firefox) >/dev/null
```

Despite the CONSEQUENCES OF ERRORS section of the [POSIX `tee` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/tee.html#tag_20_127) specifying that `tee` should continue writing to other outputs if a single output fails, GNU `tee`'s maintainers [justify this behavior](https://bug-coreutils.gnu.narkive.com/QHXlzcBn/tee-logs-no-output-if-stdout-is-closed) on the basis that signals other than SIGINT are supposed to be handled as default, and SIGPIPE is a signal.